# Omnichannel-How the workitem will be complete

Tags: salesforce

In omnichannel, I am routing custom object to agents. it is assiging the agents that custom object records. But how can I define compltion of that task? So that new records can be routed to that agent?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, salesforce marks the task to be completed once the work **tab is closed** by the agent.

As in your case it's the **Custom Object** that is being routed, so you have to write **a trigger on the object to close** or mark the **related task as completed** on some particular criteria.

Comment: On closing the tab, agentwork status is closed. But I want to close it when my custom object status field is set to completed. I am updating the agentwork to Closed but omnichannel is not remving it from agent bucket.